# g++: which ways exist to find out which template specialization has been chosen by compiler?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, template-specialization

In case you're in doubt which specialization of template the compiler has chosen in a specific case - which methods you know how to find out? (preferably without changing the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None without changing the code.

For a `template class`, you can easily expose a public

```
enum {which=0};
```

in the first specialization (including the base), and increment `=0` in each specialization after.  Then just check `Z<Args...>::which` and you'll know which was picked.

For template functions, you are mostly out of luck: but you really shouldn't be specializing template functions anyhow (overload instead).

If the return value isn't used, you can do a similar trick (`std::integral_constant<int, 0>`) with it.  If the function use is limited to that one use, you can change each of the specializations to generate a distinct error (such as `static_assert(false, "specialization 0");`), which will only kick off (in practice) when the specialization is instantiated.